# Mean and variance of distance to a point on a circle

Tags: probability-distributions

If $P$ is a random point on the circle $x^2+y^2=1$, what are the mean and variance $P$'s distance to $(0,1)$?

The random variable has the function
$$X=\sqrt{-2x+2}$$
can't quite figure out what to do next...

Comment: Hello, what is your take on this? You need to add what you have done yourself.

Comment: Hi. I took the distance between point (0,1) and any (x,y) as $\sqrt ((x-1)^2 + y^2)$ then substituted $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ to get X = $\sqrt (-2x+2)$ can't quite figure out what to do next..

Comment: Considering half of the circle, I think since you choose randomly, then the ditance will be uniformly distributed between the lowest value and the highest value.

Comment: Considering half of the circle, the distance will be uniformly distributed between $0$, the lowest value, and $2$, the highest value.

Thus, the mean will be $\mu = \frac{2+0}{2} = 1$ and the variance will be $\frac{(2-0)^2}{12}=\frac{1}{3}$.

For the complete circle, the probabilities will be doubled and we should find a way to relate them. However, I am not sure if it's right.

Comment: You have given me a place to start. thanks!

Comment: @Cardinal There is no reason to believe from the offset that the distance is uniformly distributed. What makes you say that?

Comment: @Isaac Browne. I suppose the probability of of each point on the circle is the same. And each point on the half-circle translates to a unique distance.

Comment: @Cardinal Yes, unfortunately, this does not imply that the distance is uniformly distributed. There are bijective functions which are not uniformly distributed, such as $y=x^3$, which has a higher density of $x$ values towards $y=0$

Comment: @Issac Browne I see. Thanks for making it clear. I was thinking discretely while distance is continuous !!! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we are supposed to choose a random point on the circle, I think it is best to write our circle as $(\cos(t),\sin(t))$ in order that we go through each point at the same speed ($1$), and thus count them equally. Then we can write our definitions of mean and variance as follows (I only go from $t=0$ to $t=\pi$ because of symmetry. 
$$E(X) = \frac{\int_0^\pi \sqrt{(1-\cos(t))^2+\sin^2(t)}dt}{\pi}$$
$$E(X^2) = \frac{\int_0^\pi (1-\cos(t))^2+\sin^2(t)dt}{\pi}$$
$$\mu(X) = E(X^2)-E(X)^2$$
Now it's just evaluating integrals. If you need more help, just ask!